# Background colour not coming in print preview of r shiny output

Tags: r, shiny

R Shiny is perfectly showing the output. But, while trying to print the shiny output from the Chrome or Internet Explorer, I am not getting the background colours in the print preview also the page saved as pdf did not show the background colours. I have also kept the option to "Show Background".

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
h2("Text Background colour YELLOW not showing in Print Preview",
    style="background-color: yellow")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Below are the screenshot:

[image: This is the browser view of R Shiny output]

[image: This is the print preview]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the ‘!important’ to any css style you add to your application forces it to use this style rather than inheriting the style from somewhere and changing the background back to white.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Text Background colour YELLOW not showing in Print Preview",
     style="background-color: yellow!important")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had added the explanation.   Adding the ‘!important’ to any css style you add to your application forces it to use this style rather than inheriting the style from somewhere and changing the background back to white.

Comment: It's not entirely true that important will override. If other conflicting `!important` statements are used it'll fall back to priority with the most specific. It's best to avoid important statement as it just introduces a new layer of specificity into your CSS which can be avoided.